# error al utiliza la directiva ngFor

Tags: html5, angular, ngfor

// Buenos Dias estoy tratando de recorre un array  con la directiva ngFor y me ocurre este error en mi pagina html:

```
Property 'linea' does not exist on type 'object'.ngtsc(2339)

esto es los que tengo en mi component //`introducir el código aquí`
entradas: object[];
  constructor(){
    this.entradas= [
      {linea:'angular'},
      {linea:'java'},
      {linea:'python'},
      {linea:'Jscript'},
      {linea:'Visual Basic'}
    ]
     }
codigo
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let entrada of entradas">{{entrada.linea}}/li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Cambia `object[]` por `any[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba de la siguiente forma:

```
entradas:any[];

constructor(){
this.entradas = [
      {linea:'angular'},
      {linea:'java'},
      {linea:'python'},
      {linea:'html'}
    ]
}
```

---

```
 <mat-form-field >
   <mat-select  formControlName="linea">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let entrada of entradas; let i = index;" >
       {{entradas[i].linea}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: muchas gracias , me funciono

Comment: ok amigo, recuerda verificar la respuesta!

Comment: como puedo hacerlo? , soy nuevo aqui

Comment: a la lado  izquierdo de  mi respuesta hay un check y tienes que darle click alli

Comment: listo  verifique tu respuesta